# Finding week of the month from the date in databricks SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to get the week_of_the_month from the date in databricks sql

Here is my SQL:

```
with date as (
  select EXTRACT(DAY FROM '2017-01-01') as day
)

select case
       when day < 8 then '1'
       when day < 15 then '2'
       when day < 22 then '3'
       else '4'
       end as week_of_month
```

The above sql fails in some of the edge cases. For example `2010-03-31`, then the `week_of_month = 5`

How do I find the week_of_month in databricks SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it, you'd add yet another `when` clause

```
select case
         when day < 8 then '1'
         when day < 15 then '2'
         when day < 22 then '3'
         when day < 29 then '4'   --> new
         else '5'                 --> modified
       end as week_of_month
```